# How to resolve java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, classloader, liferay-7

I am getting the below error whenever i am deploying war file of Liferay portlet in Eclipse.Can anyone help me to know why is it occurring and how to resolve it.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, com/liferay/portal/spring/extender/internal/context/ModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor, and its superclass loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory used in the signature
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleApplicationContextRegistrator._createApplicationContext(ModuleApplicationContextRegistrator.java:138)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleApplicationContextRegistrator.start(ModuleApplicationContextRegistrator.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor756.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeMethod(InvocationUtil.java:111)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeCallbackMethod(InvocationUtil.java:66)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invokeCallbackMethod(ComponentImpl.java:769)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invoke(ComponentImpl.java:760)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.bindService(ComponentImpl.java:705)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.access$400(ComponentImpl.java:54)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl$7.run(ComponentImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.runTask(SerialExecutor.java:137)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.runTasks(SerialExecutor.java:119)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.calculateStateChanges(ComponentImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.start(ComponentImpl.java:440)
    at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:167)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleApplicationContextExtender$ModuleApplicationContextExtension.start(ModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:228)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.addingBundle(AbstractExtender.java:192)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.startTracking(AbstractExtender.java:150)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.doStart(AbstractExtender.java:142)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.start(AbstractExtender.java:114)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleApplicationContextExtender.activate(ModuleApplicationContextExtender.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:224)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:617)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:501)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:302)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:294)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:906)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:748)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:429)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:657)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:341)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:403)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$200(Activator.java:54)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:278)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1258)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1230)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

Comment: Show your dependencies

Answer (score 6):

java.lang.LinkageError happens when code is compiled with dependency version say v1 and then is running with dependency version say v2.

Explanation sample:
While compiling you are using this Parent class of v1 (assume that's coming from Liferay)

```
class Parent {
    public void method(String s) {
        s = "Hello " + s;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

// this is your project class
class Child extends Parent {
    @Overridden
    public void method(String s) {
        super.method(s);
        System.out.println("Hello from child : " + s);
    } 
}
```

So it is compiling fine while building the project jar.

However at the runtime you are using a Parent class of version v2 who has got the method definition like `public void method(String s, int i)`. Hence that's not able to link your class to that parent class and so the error.

Here in your case, the runtime version and compile time version of the library containing class `com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.context.ModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor` are different. Keep both versions same as your compile time and it will be all good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.I don't know how i missed it but thanks for the save !!